# Unable to cross compiling linux kernel on eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am trying to compile Linux on Eclipse. I am compiling for x86 only but want to use my tool chain. I created a project as "File -> C Project -> Linux gcc" and gave the location of my Linux kernel. I right clicked on "Project -> Properties -> C/C++ build -> Settings" and changed GCC C compiler and linker and include path to my toolchain.

On C/C++ build, I replaced make with below command

```
make ARCH=x86 CC=/home/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/corei7-64-poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux-
```

Now when I try to build, I am getting below error

```
 make ARCH=x86 CC=/home/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr   
 /bin/corei7-64-poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux- all 
 Building file: ../virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.c
 Invoking: GCC C Compiler
 /home/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr/bin/corei7-64-         
 poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux-gcc -I/home/poky/build/tmp/sysroots     
 /i686-linux/usr/include -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.d" -MT"virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.d" -o "virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.o" "../virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.c"
  ../virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.c:19:23: fatal error: linux/cpu.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/cpu.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  make: *** [virt/kvm/arm/arch_timer.o] Error 1
```

How can I cross compile Linux kernel on Eclipse? I want to use my own toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiling works as it should but it seems that you haven't yet added all necessary include paths.
As the error msg already mentions, the compiler can't find linux/cpu.h

You can add additional include paths at: Project->Properties->C/C++ General-> Paths and Symbols

Comment: Thanks lilUnicorn, i added include path. Is this right way to cross compile linux on eclipse ?

Comment: Are you actually trying to compile Linux Kernel via eclipse ?
If yes, i would recommend doing it on command line with default make commands. All neccesary information can be then set up with "make menuconfig".
I have never seen someone compiling the kernel with eclipse ^^. Do it the old fashioned way ;-).

Comment: Thanks lilUnicorn, but i need to do in IDE, this is the requirement

Comment: Ok i understand, assuming your .config file is setup correct and you chose the correct paths to your compiler, i would guess it should work. But i can't back it up with actual knowledge, never tried it.

Comment: HI lilUnicorn, which information i need to add in  paths and symbols. Where exactly i need to add toolchain information

Comment: Try this: [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source) to set all Paths and includes. Additionaly it gives you the advantage of browsing the code more easy.
make ARCH=x86 CC=/home/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/i686-linux/usr /bin/corei7-64-poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux-
Here it should be enough to set CC to CC=x86_64-poky-linux-gcc

The rest should be ok if you have any more problems i will have a closer look at the problem when i'm back home from work.